# Martingales of random walk

Tags: martingales, random-walk

Let $S_n$ be a random walk process defined by $$S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$$ with $X_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $X_i$ are i.i.d.

I'm trying to prove that the quantity $(S_n-n\mu)^2-n\sigma^2$ is a martingale, that is:

$$\Bbb E \bigl[( S_{n+1}-(n+1)\mu)^2-(n+1)\sigma^2 \mid \mathcal{F_{t}} \bigr]=(S_{n}-n\mu)^2-n\sigma^2$$
where $\mathcal{F_{t}}$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$.
My strategy is based on the extension of another related proof. Showing that $S_n-n\mu$ is a martingale.

We can write $S_{n+1}$ as: 
$$S_{n+1} = S_n+X_{n+1}$$ 
and taking the expectation of both sides and conditioning on $S_n$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\Bbb E \bigl[(S_{n+1}\mid S_n\bigr]
&=\Bbb E \bigl[S_n+X_{n+1}\mid S_n \bigr]\\
&=S_n+\Bbb E \bigl[X_{n+1}\mid S_n \bigr]\\
&=S_n+\Bbb E \bigl[X_{n+1}\bigr]\\
&=S_n+\mu,
\end{align*}
where the third step follows because $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $S_n$.
Subtracting $(n+1)\mu$ from both sides of the equation:
\begin{align*}
\Bbb E \bigl[(S_{n+1}-(n+1)\mu \mid S_n\bigr]
&=S_n+\mu(1-(n+1))\\
&=S_n-n\mu\\
\end{align*}
we have the claim.

Going back to the case of interest, we have that:
$$S^2_{n+1} = S^2_n+X^2_{n+1}+2 S_n X_{n+1}$$
Taking the expectation of both sides and conditioning on $S^2_n$, we have:
\begin{align*}
\Bbb E \bigl[S^2_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F_{t}} \bigr]
&=\Bbb E \bigl[S^{2}_{n}+X^2_{n+1}+2 S_n X_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F_{t}}\bigr]\\
&=S^2_{n}+\mathbb{E}\big[X^2_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F_{t}}\big]+2 S_n\mathbb{E}\big[X_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F_{t}}\big]\\
&=S^2_{n}+\mathbb{E}\big[X^2_{n+1}\big]+2 S_n\mathbb{E}\big[X_{n+1}\big]\\
&=S^2_{n}+\sigma^2+2 S_n \mu\\
\end{align*}

At this point, I'm stuck because I don't know which quantity I should subtract from both sides to complete the proof. For sure, I should subtract $(n+1)\sigma^2$, 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\bigl[S^2_{n+1}-(n+1)\sigma^2\mid S^{2}_{n}\bigr]
&=S^{2}_{n}+\sigma^2(1-(n+1))+2 S_n \mu\\
&=S^{2}_{n}-n\sigma^2+2 S_n \mu\\
\end{align}
but I'm still far from closing the proof, because I need to subtract other elements that I'm not able to identify.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that $S^2_{n+1} = S^2_n+X^2_{n+1}$? It looks more like $S_{n+1} = S_n+X_{n+1} \Rightarrow S^2_{n+1} = (S_n+X_{n+1})^2 = S^2_n+X^2_{n+1} + 2S_nX_{n+1}$

Comment: Also $(\sigma(S_n))_{n\geq 1}$ doesn't seem to be a filtration, should really have $(\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n))_{n\geq 1}$ or something similar

Comment: Thank you guys for your observations. I think that both of you are correct. I forgot to specify that the $X_{i}$ are i.i.d., for this reason I wasn't considering the term $2S_n X_{n+1}$. I updated my question with your corrections, but I still don't see which quantity I should subtract. I'm leaving the first proof without introducing the filtration, because I find it in the Klebaner's book.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first remark that the notation $\mathcal{F}_t$ doesn't make sense at all. Instead of $\mathcal{F}_t$ you should use $\mathcal{F}_n$, i.e.

$$\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$$

since the right side depends on $n$ and not on $t$.

Moreover, your proof of $S_n-n \cdot \mu$ being a martingale is not correct; you have to replace the conditional expectiation on $S_n$ by the conditional expectation on $\mathcal{F}_n$. (Note that $\sigma(S_n)$ does not define a filtration; $S_n -n \cdot \mu$ is a martingale with respect to $\mathcal{F}_n$.)

---

**Solution 1** Let $(M_n,\mathcal{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a martingale such that $M_n \in L^2$. Then we have

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(M_{n+1}^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_n) &= M_n^2 + \mathbb{E}(M_{n+1}^2-M_n^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_n) \\ &= M_n^2 + \mathbb{E}((M_{n+1}-M_n)^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_n) \\ &= M_n^2 + (A_{n+1}-A_n) \tag{1} \end{align*}$$

where $$A_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}((M_n-M_{n-1})^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_n)$$ This shows that $M_n^2 - A_n$ is a martingale. $A$ is called compensator of $M$.

In order to apply this general result, we set

$$M_n = S_n - n \cdot \mu$$

and obtain

$$\begin{align*} A_n &= \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}((S_{n}-(n) \cdot \mu - S_{n-1}+(n-1) \cdot \mu)^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_n)  \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}((X_{n}-\mu)^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_n) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \underbrace{\mathbb{E}((X_{n}-\mu)^2)}_{\sigma^2} = n \cdot \sigma^2\end{align*}$$

Consequently, we see that $M_n^2-A_n = (S_n-n \cdot \mu)^2-n \cdot \sigma^2$ is a martingale.

---

**Solution 2** If you prefer straight-forward calculations:

$$\begin{align*} &\quad \mathbb{E}((S_{n+1}-(n+1) \cdot \mu)^2-(n+1) \cdot \sigma^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_n) \\
&= \mathbb{E}\bigg[ ((S_n-n \cdot \mu)+(X_{n+1}-\mu))^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_n \bigg] - (n+1) \cdot \sigma^2 \\
&= (S_n-n \cdot \mu)^2 + 2 (S_n-n \cdot \mu) \cdot \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}-\mu \mid \mathcal{F}_n)}_{\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}-\mu)=0} + \underbrace{\mathbb{E}((X_{n+1}-\mu)^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_n)}_{\mathbb{E}((X_{n+1}-\mu)^2) = \sigma^2} - (n+1) \cdot \sigma^2 \\
&= (S_n-n \cdot \mu)^2- n \cdot \sigma^2\end{align*}$$

using that $(S_n-n \cdot \mu)$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable and $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.